# Writing Database Transaction Log to Kafka - How?

Tags: apache-kafka, data-warehouse

I would like to begin with introducing Apache Kafka as the singular source of feeding  my Data Warehouse. The way, I want to do it is by writing transaction log of my source systems to Kafka.
Is there a component already available to use or do I need to build something from scratch?

Comment: Look into Kafka Connect and https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/